# Как разделить строку на части?

Tags: c#

Есть строка

```
string s = "Я пошел гулять, но на улице шел дождь!"
```

Как с помощью функции `Split()` разделить строки по "ничему", т.е. чтобы в результате кроме отдельных слов, отдельно имелись еще и **знаки препинания**?:

Comment: А что вы хотите для строки `"Как-то раз д'Артаньян в году 1633—1644..."`?

Comment: В идеале бы конечно: [как-то] [раз] [д'Артаньян] [в] [году] [1633-1644] [.] [.] [.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
var words = Regex.Split("Я пошел гулять, но на улице шел дождь!", @"\b\s*").Where(s => s!="").ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", words));
```

Изменение для примера с д'Артаньяном (многоточие получается одним знаком):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
var words = Regex.Split("Как-то раз д'Артаньян в году 1633-1644...", @"(?![-'])(?<![-'])\b\s*").Where(s => s!="").ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", words));
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, правда без Split

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string tmp = @"Как-то раз д'Артаньян в году 1633-1644...";
Regex r = new Regex(@"([\w'-]+)|([!?.,])");
var result = r.Matches(tmp);
```

Подходит к обоим вышеуказанным примерам

Comment: Тут два недостатка. Во-первых, требуется перечислять все знаки препинания, что проблематично (можно просто забыть - тире например нет никакого, а можно и что-то из юникодных откопать - их там очень много) - т. е. никогда не знаешь, не потерялось ли что-то из строки. Во-вторых, результат не является IEnumerable<string>, но тут можно применить Select.

Comment: @Qwertiy - добавте Select и ToList, вопрос ведь был не об этом. Что касается знаков препинания, то, с моей точки зрения, гораздо проблематичней получить что-нибудь неожиданое, чем перечислить все ожидаемое; но да вы правы, наверное это недостаток.